# Save Video as Frames OpenCV{PY}

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to create a program which saves .jpg images taken from the webcam(frames).
What my program do for now is, opening a webcam, taking one and only one frame, and then everything stops.

What i would like to have is more than one frame
My error-code is this one:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
count = 0

while True:
   # Capture frame-by-frame
   ret, frame = cap.read()

   # Our operations on the frame come here
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % ret, frame)     # save frame as JPEG file
   count +=1

   # Display the resulting frame
   cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
   if cv2.waitKey(10):
      break
```

Comment: is your formatting just in stack overflow wrong? you have to indent everything after the `while True:` line by one space (or even more? I'm not so familiar with Python).

Comment: You were right, there was no indentation. 
Anyway now its fine

Comment: with latest changes (from answers below): does it still stop after one frame or does it continue to run (until you press a key) and show all the images but just doesnt save them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually it sounds like you are always saving your image with the same name
because you are concatenating ret instead of count in the imwrite method

try this :

```
name = "frame%d.jpg"%count
cv2.imwrite(name, frame)     # save frame as JPEG file
```

Comment: Still saving just frame named 'frame0.jpg', not saving any frame after this one

Comment: Have you combined with Sansuiso's answer?

Comment: Yes, i have tried that combination but still saving just 1 frame

Comment: Is the jpeg file valid ?

Comment: Yes, but for now i found i way to save the frames, but now it overwrite the same file all the time, so that i don't have a list of frames but just one that change every second . %d don't work in imwrite

Comment: can you print `count` and `ret` to the terminal for each image please?

Comment: you could assemble a new name in a separated string then pass it as argument to imwrite ?

Answer (score 5):

use this -

```
count = 0
cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, frame)
count = count+1
```

Answer (score 2):

When no key is pressed and the time delay expires, `cv2.waitKey` returns `-1`. You can check it in the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey).

Basically, all you have to do is changing slightly the end of your program:

```
# Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
if cv2.waitKey(10) != -1:
    break
```

Comment: Hi sansuiso! Thanks for the answer.The problem is that is still saving just one frame and i don't know why!! 
I would like to save more frames ( for ex 10, 1 every sec ) 
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Though this is late I have to say that prtkp's answer is what you needed... the , ret value you use to enumerate your images is wrong. Ret is only a boolean... so while it detects the image it its placing a one there for the name of the image...

I just used this... with a c=0 on the header

```
 cv2.imwrite("img/frame %d.jpg" % c,img)
    c=c+1
```